# Whats the most effective way to segue into multiple different view controllers from a collection view?

Tags: uicollectionview, swift3

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wY6bI.jpg) is my collection view I need each image to be segue to a different view controller. Whats the simplest way to construct this feature?

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  before asking queries

Answer (score 0):

You can check multiple view's segue connection's identifiers before navigation for particular viewController: -

```
    let showAddressSegueIdentifier = "gotoAddressdetails"
    let showNameSegueIdentifier = "gotoNamedetails"

         //MARK: - Navigation 
          override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
                //Verify segue identifier
                if segue.identifier == showNameSegueIdentifier {
                    if let indexPath = collectionView?.indexPath(for: sender as! UICollectionViewCell) {
                        let controller = segue.destination as! FirstViewController
                        let data = details[indexPath.item]
                        controller.name =  data["name"] as? String ?? ""
                    }
                }else if segue.identifier == showAddressSegueIdentifier {
                    if let indexPath = collectionView?.indexPath(for: sender as! UICollectionViewCell) {
                        let controller = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
                        let data = details[indexPath.item]
                        controller.address =  data["address"] as? String ?? ""
                    }
                }
            }
```